# scala - 14-digit timestamp string to Instant

Tags: scala, timestamp

I have a `14-digit timestamp` (Format: "YYYYMMDDhhmmss") which i want to convert to `Instant` object.

What is correct way to do it?

Something like:

```
import java.time.Instant

val t1 = "20010531021254"

Instant.parse(t1) //Doesn't work
//What i'de like to receive:
res0: java.time.Instant = 2001-05-31T02:12:54.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `Instant.parse()` to work, the string has to be in an acceptable format.

```
import java.time.{Instant, LocalDateTime}
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val t1 = "20010531021254"
Instant.parse(LocalDateTime.parse(t1, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))
                           .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME) + "Z")
// or                      .toString + "Z")

//res0: java.time.Instant = 2001-05-31T02:12:54Z
```

There are likely better ways to get this done, but this is how I got it to work.